# Uniqueness of Inorder, Preorder, and Postorder traversal with null elements

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-tree, tree-traversal, preorder

We all know that different binary trees can have the same *inorder*, *preorder*, or *postorder* traversal. But if we were to include `null` elements into a *preorder* traversal, then result of the traversal would be unique as long as the trees are unique. Consider these two trees:

```
  3                      3
 /                        \
4            vs.           4
```

Their normal *preorder* traversal would be `{3,4}` for both, but if we were to include `null` elements, then their traversal would be `{3,4,null,null,null}` and `{3,null,4,null,null}` respectively, making the traversal unique.

**My question is, would this be true for inorder and postorder traversals as well? And how can we prove it?**

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It is true for a postorder traversal, because that's just the reverse of the preorder traversal of the reversed tree.

It is NOT true for an inorder traversal, which would always start with null, end with null, and alternate between nulls and nodes.

E.g., these trees:

```
  B          D    
 / \        / \
A   D      B   E
   / \    / \
  C   E  A   C
```

both produce

```
null, A, null, B, null, C, null, D, null, E, null
```

Comment: Can there be one formal convincing proof for the same?

Comment: Easily done by induction from the leaves, but no good reason to do it.  Anyone who would be convinced by such a proof, but not by this demonstration, is just looking for long words and smart-sounding language.

Comment: Yes, agree with you. But such proofs are often required for theoretical examinations. That's why was interested in them.

Answer (score 0):

The inorder is not right.
e.g.:

```
      2                     2
     / \                   / \
    2   n                 n   2
   / \                       / \
  n   n                     n   n
```

They are both [n, 2, n, 2, n]

Preorder and postorder are right because with 2 null, we can determine a parent, and this parent must be a child of other node, and so on. We can always determine a unique parent node. But this is not true for inorder.